# Is there any way if i want to use group by function in my sql query

Tags: sql

I want to Groupby REFId which I Assigned for my ts.Id. and the SQL query I have written can I make it more simple or better.

I have provided the query, I tried to use Group By function to group by same REF id together but getting Error.

```
 Select ts.ID, 
    ts.RequestName, 
    ts.OncorStationName,
    ts.Category, 
    ts.ReceptionDate, 
    ts.County, 
    ts.Voltage, 
    ts.TSCAssignment,
    ts.MWCapacity,
    ts.InServiceDateRequested,
    ts.FEASignedDate,
    ts.DSASignedDate,
    ts.TransmissionServicesComments,
 (CASE 
 When (t.id = 1353 OR t.id = 1527 ) then 6
 When (t.id = 1468 OR t.id = 1462) then 7
 When (t.id = 1458 OR t.id = 1592 ) then 13
 When (t.id = 1594 OR t.id = 1622) then 15 
 When (t.id = 1369 OR t.id = 1602 OR  t.id = 1616 OR t.id = 1627) then 39
 When (t.id = 1367 OR t.id = 1419) then 4       
 When (t.id = 1549 Or t.id = 1625 ) then 93
else Null End) As Ref 

from  [rpt].[TransmissionServicesRpt] ts
inner join [dbo].[TransmissionServicePOI] poi on ts.id = 
 poi.TransmissionServiceId
 inner join [rpt].[TransmissionServicesRpt] t on t.id = ts.id
 Where ts.Status = 'active'
 Order by ts.FEASignedDate DESC;
```

Ts.id is related to each other and assigned the same REF if they are Related so now I want to group by REF id together so I can see related project together.

```
 (CASE 
 When (t.id = 1353 OR t.id = 1527 ) then 6
 When (t.id = 1468 OR t.id = 1462) then 7
 When (t.id = 1458 OR t.id = 1592 ) then 13
 When (t.id = 1594 OR t.id = 1622) then 15 
 When (t.id = 1369 OR t.id = 1602 OR  t.id = 1616 OR t.id = 1627) then 39
 When (t.id = 1367 OR t.id = 1419) then 4       
 When (t.id = 1549 Or t.id = 1625 ) then 93
else Null End) As Ref
```

Comment: What is your error please

Comment: Also, what is the database you are using?

Comment: It is not really clear what you're trying to accomplish... What are the values you want to group? Could we see the query you tried and the error it gave you?

Comment: Select ts.ID, 
  ts.RequestName, 
  s.TSCAssignment,
  ts.FEASignedDate,
  ts.DSASignedDate,
  ts.TransmissionServicesComments,
(CASE When (t.id = 1649 OR  t.id = 1642) then 17 
When (t.id = 1598 OR  t.id = 1600 OR t.id = 1601 OR t.id = 1410) then 78 
When (t.id = 1647 OR t.id = 1584  OR t.id = 1633 )then 90  
When (t.id = 1549 Or t.id = 1625 ) then 93
else Null End) As Ref 
from  [rpt].[TransmissionServicesRpt] ts
inner join [dbo].[TransmissionServicePOI] poi on ts.id = poi.TransmissionServiceId
Where ts.Status = 'active'
Group by Ref
Order by ts.FEASignedDate DESC;

Comment: Simplifying I have project ID and I am using Case Statement to Assign REF ID if two Project id is Related (Like this case When (id = 1612 OR id = 1513 ) then 54) now i need to Group by REF IF which is 54 (When (t.id = 1612 OR t.id = 1513 ) then 54). So I can see the two related project together

Comment: To use the GroupBy clause, you need to use an aggregate function (sum, count, etc...) in one of your Select fields otherwise it won't work...

Comment: When you say you want to group them, do you mean just to order them so they're side by side? If that's the case, you could just do "Order by Ref"